# How do I keep VS Code Debugger for Chrome from breaking on VM exceptions?

Tags: ionic2, visual-studio-code

When running an Ionic 2 project, Visual Studio Code's Debugger for Chrome plugin consistently breaks inside the bowels of Chrome and a VM#### file is generated at the exception source. It appears it may be related to XMLHttpRequest.send().

It doesn't cause any evident runtime issues with the app, so I'd love to just figure out how to prevent the debugger from trapping errors there (while still keeping the All Exceptions option enabled). Bonus points if you can figure how to resolve the exception entirely.

Comment: BTW, this happens with a brand spankin' new vanilla ionic project.